# Which is given more importance Precision or Recall in classification report for obtaining a better prediction model

Tags: machine-learning, classification

For a classification problem in machine learning in classification report out of precision and recall which one is given more importance to get better model?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `python`, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: @desertnaut if tags are the issue please let me know what are proper tags so that i can tag them properly. Like I said am new here and trying to learn. So your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @desertnaut I have updated the Tag to classification hope it should and I would be obliged if you can upvote the question.

Comment: Please notice that the issue is always the question itself, and never the tags.

Comment: @desertnaut how come the question is off topic ?Is there some guideline which says only code related questions should be asked and not the theory?

Comment: Indeed there is, and it has already been provided (you were advised to see some stuff).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually *depends* on your classification problem.

First, you need to understand the difference between *precision* and *recall*.
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall) may be a good start, but I would suggest [this resource by developers.google](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/classification/precision-and-recall).

[image: precision-recall]

---

Now imagine you're trying to track covid cases with a classifier.
The classifier tells you if a patient is carrying covid or not.

Are you more interested in:

**A)** Identifying **all** possible covid cases?

**B)** Being sure that if you identify a covid case that one is *actually* a real covid case?

If **A)** is more important you should focus on **recall**. On the other hand, if you're more interested in **B)**, then **precision** is probably what you're looking for.

Be aware though:

---

Let's say you're testing `1000` possible cases, and let's say `500` of them are positive, we just don't know yet. You use the classifier and it tells you all `1000` people are positive.

So you have:

`true_positives` = `500`

`false_negatives` = `0`

`recall = true_positives / (true_positives + false_negatives)`

`recall = 500 / (500 + 0) = 1`

So here you have a good recall, but you're not precise, nor accurate.

---

What I'm trying to express is that one shouldn't focus on one metric over another, but always keep a broad view on the problem.

However, if you want to focus on just one metric to sum up both precision and recall, that's what the [F score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-score) was made for.

Comment: thanks for the explanation actually I was asked this question during an Interview and was unable to answer. I tried googling the answer but it was not clear enough for me.